# Pulling data out of a mapped array to calculate sums in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mapping

I have 2 data sets that are currently being mapped over. the second data set is being mapped over inside of the first data set and rendering the values onto a modal for the user to view. I am however trying to take this second data set that is being mapped over out of its map sequence to render a sum total of each associated data point. For instance, I have a 'goalValue', an 'actualValue', and a 'result' value each of which belong to a specified category.

I should like to grab these data points when they are mapped over and push them out of the map into a separate array and or state to calculate a total that can be rendered at the bottom of the table in the modal itself. I created a separate component called ResultCalculator that takes in each value within the 'category.'  Currently the state that i am trying to push the mapped values to is causing an infinite loop. I thought that maybe i could use a 'useEffect' but that isn't possible inside of a callback function.

I have added the code below for reference. Any potential insight would be greatly appreciated. I have been working on this for the last few hours whilst gaining no headway. Any search I've typed in on google has yet to render any valuable response.

Here is the code for the mappings.

```
const Reports = () => {
  // declare const for grabbing user profile
  const userProfile = () => {
    axios.get('/api/users/profile', {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('user')}`
      }
    }
    )
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
        setUsers({ ...users, months: res.data.months })
      })
  }

  // BUTTON TO DELETE A MONTH
  const handleDeleteMonth = (id) => {
    console.log(id)
    axios.delete(`/api/months/${id}`, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('user')}`
      }
    }).then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      userProfile()
    })
  }

  //GRAB THE USER PROFILE
  const [users, setUsers] = useState({ months: [] })
  useEffect(() => {
    userProfile()
  }, [])

  // defining modal styles
  const style = {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    width: 1000,
    bgcolor: 'background.paper',
    border: '2px solid #000',
    boxShadow: 24,
    p: 4,
  };

  // defining modal state
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState({});
  const handleOpen = monthId => setOpen(prev => ({ ...prev, [monthId]: true }));
  const handleClose = monthId => setOpen(prev => ({ ...prev, [monthId]: false }));

  //RESULT CALCULATION STATES
  const [actualsArray, setActualsArray] = useState(0)
  // const [goalsResult, setGoalsResult] = useState(0)
  // const [resultsResult, setResultsResult] = useState(0)

  return (
    <>
      <NavBar></NavBar>
      <br></br>      <br></br>
      <h1 style={{ color: "white", textAlign: "center", fontSize: "50px" }}>Budget Summaries</h1>
      <br></br>      <br></br>

      <Container>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={0} md={1}>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} md={10}>
            <TableContainer component={Paper}>
              <Table sx={{ minWidth: 700 }} aria-label="customized table">
                <TableHead>
                  <TableRow>
                    <StyledTableCell style={{ fontSize: "25px" }}>Month</StyledTableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                  {users.months.map(month => (
                    <StyledTableRow key={month._id}>
                      <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
                        <Button onClick={() => handleOpen(month._id)} align="left">{month.name}</Button>
                        <Button style={{ minWidth: 200 }} align="right" onClick={() => {handleDeleteMonth(month._id)}}>Delete</Button>
                        <Modal
                          open={open[month._id]}
                          onClose={() => handleClose(month._id)}
                          aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
                          aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
                        >
                          <Box sx={style}>
                            <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
                              <Container>
                                < Grid container spacing={2} >
                                  <Grid item xs={0} md={1}>
                                  </Grid>
                                  <Grid item xs={12} md={10}>
                                    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
                                      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 700 }} aria-label="customized table">
                                        <TableHead>
                                          <TableRow>
                                            <StyledTableCell style={{ fontSize: "25px" }}>Categories</StyledTableCell>
                                            <StyledTableCell style={{ fontSize: "25px" }} align="right">Spent</StyledTableCell>
                                            <StyledTableCell style={{ fontSize: "25px" }} align="right">Goals</StyledTableCell>
                                            <StyledTableCell style={{ fontSize: "25px" }} align="right">Results</StyledTableCell>
                                            <StyledTableCell style={{ fontSize: "25px" }} align="right"></StyledTableCell>
                                          </TableRow>
                                        </TableHead>
                                        <TableBody>


                                          {month.categories.map(category => (
                                            
                                            <>
                                            <StyledTableRow key={category.name}>
                                              <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                                {category.name}
                                              </StyledTableCell>
                                              <StyledTableCell align="right">{category.actualValue}</StyledTableCell>
                                              <StyledTableCell align="right">{category.goalValue}</StyledTableCell>
                                              <StyledTableCell align="right">{category.result}</StyledTableCell>
                                                <StyledTableCell align="right"></StyledTableCell>
                                            </StyledTableRow>
                                            </>
                                          ))}
                                          <StyledTableRow>
                                            <styledTableCell component="th" scope="row">Net</styledTableCell>
                                            <StyledTableCell align="right"><ResultCalculator/></StyledTableCell>
                                            <StyledTableCell align="right"><ResultCalculator/></StyledTableCell>
                                            <StyledTableCell align="right"><ResultCalculator/></StyledTableCell>
                                            <StyledTableCell align="right"></StyledTableCell>
                                          </StyledTableRow>
                                        </TableBody>
                                      </Table>
                                    </TableContainer>
                                  </Grid>
                                  <Grid item xs={0} md={1}>
                                  </Grid>
                                </Grid >
                              </Container >
                            </Typography>
                          </Box>
                        </Modal>
                      </StyledTableCell>
                    </StyledTableRow>
                  ))}
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </TableContainer>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={0} md={1}>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
      <br></br><br></br>
      <hr style={{ color: "white" }}></hr>
      <Footer></Footer>
    </>
  )
}
```

I also will include the exterior component called ResultCalculator. There are some things that are commented out because I am currently just trying to get 1 value to calculate correctly before trying the other 2.

```
> function ResultCalculator(actualValue, goalValue, result) {
> 
>   const [actualsResult, setActualsResult] = useState(0)   
 // const [goalsResult, setGoalsResult] = useState(0)   
 // const [resultsResult,setResultsResult] = useState(0)
> 
>   let actuals = 0
 // let goals = 0
 // let results = 0
> 
>   const actualCalculator = (actualValue) => {
>     actuals = actuals + actualValue   }
> 
>   // const goalCalculator = (goalValue) => {  
  //   goals = goals + goalValue  
  //   return goals  
   // }
> 
>   // const resultCalculator = (result) => {
  //   results = results + result  
  //   return results   
   // } 
   
      actualCalculator(actualValue)
> 
>   // goalCalculator()
   // resultCalculator() 

    useEffect(() => {
>     setActualsResult(actuals)   
    }, [])
> 
>   // setGoalsResult(goals) 
  // setResultsResult(results)
> 
>   return (
>     <>
>       {actualsResult}
>       {/* {goalsResult}
>     {resultsResult} */}
>     </>   )
> 
> }
```

Comment: It is observed that when a React component is rendered as `<ResultCalculator/>`, the props `actualValue, goalValue, result` do not appear to be passed to it. Also: would it be acceptable to avoid having a separate component `ResultCalculator`? If you would share the two arrays, it may be possible to calculate the desired totals within the `Reports` component itself, I think.

Comment: I found a way to push data to the array for calculations in the ResultCalculator component, however doing so just calculates totals for each month and renders them on whichever month is selected. I'm wondering if How i could calculate those totals within the map. I haven't been able to come up with any logic for that though.